# Scheme Adding Terms from lists

Tags: scheme

I am writing a scheme program for performing operations on polynomials. I am currently working on a method that combines all like terms. For example, if I have the polynomial: 1x^2 + 2x^2 + 4x^3, the function should combine the likes terms 1x^2 and 2x^2 and output the final polynomial 3x^2 + 4x^3. It uses recursion.

I first sort the polynomial. Then, if the length is zero, do nothing. I have another function I call that checks if the exponents are equal, if they are, then I add the two terms, and go through the list.

Problem I am having is:

When I check if two terms are equal, I add them together. Once I do this, I can't figure out how to add this to the original list and pass that list in when making the recursive call. I know I am supposed to use "cons" to add to the front of a list. I know I am supposed to use cdr(cdr list) in order to skip the two terms that I added already.

How do I make a new list inside the function to add to the original list?. This is what I have done so far. Some of it does not work. (was trying out different things) The part I am stuck on is when I create 'a' and 'b' and print them. Instead of printing them, I want to put them in a list so that I can cons it with the original list. The commented out portion with the 'cons' stuff in the middle ( semicolon for comment) is what I tried so far. This is how my list is defined. First term is coefficient and second term is the exponent. Example:  (2 3) Coeff = 2, expon = 3

```
    (define p1 '((2 3)(3 2)(5 2)))

    (define (simplify p)
    (sort p GT)
    (cond [(= (length p) 0) (print 0)]
    [(= (length p) 1) (printpoly p)]
    [
     (if(EQExp? (car p) (cadr p))
     (let([a (+ (coeff (car p)) (coeff (cadr p)))])
     (let([b (expon (cadr p))])
     (print a)
     (display "x^")
     (print b)
       (printpoly(car([list '((a b))])))
     ; (printpoly y)
     ; (cons (cons ('(a) '(expon (cdr p)))) p)
     ; (cons  y p)
     ;(print (expon (car p)))
     (set! p (cdr p))
     (simplify p)
         )
       ;)
     )
     (if(> (length p) 1)
      ((printTerm (car p))
      (display " + ")
      (set! p (cdr p))
      (simplify p))
      ((=(length p) 1)
       (set! p (cdr p))
       (simplify p)
      )
      )
     )
     ]
     [else
     (set! p (cdr p))
     (simplify p)
     ]
     )
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polynomial operations can be complicated, so it is important to break the task up into many small operations. In particular you need to have a separate function that prints a polynomial. Below you will see how simplify can replace the two terms with the same exponent. What's missing is a function for printing polynomials.

```
(define the-zero-polynomial '())

(define (exponent t) ; t stands for term
  (second t))

(define (coef t) ; t 
  (first t))

(define (same-degree? t1 t2)
  (or (equal? t1 t2)
      (and (not (null? t1)) (not (null? t2))
           (= (exponent t1) (exponent t2)))))

(define p1 '((2 3) (3 2) (5 2)))

(define (simplify p) ; p is unsorted
  (simplify-sorted (sort p GT)))

(define (simplify-sorted p)
  (cond 
    [(= (length p) 0) the-zero-polynomial]
    [(= (length p) 1) p]
    [else
     ; now p = (list t1 t2 t ...)
     (let ([t1 (first p)] [t2 (second p)])
       (cond
         [(same-degree? t1 t2)
          ; same degree, replace (list t1 t2 t ...) 
          ; with                 (list t1+t2 t ...)
           (let ([t1+t2 (list (+ (coef t1) (coef t2))
                              (exponent t1))])
             (simplify-sorted (cons t1+t2 (cddr p))))]
         [else
          (cons t1 (simplify (cdr p)))]))]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Scheme has been tough to learn. I've spent over 6 hours on this one method. But it all makes sense now. I already had the printing method. I just had to make a few minor changes and add a few things to make the print work. I'll be sure to remember to break a method down into smaller methods.  :)